# OptaPy isEqual isNotEqual in python

Tags: python, optaplanner, optapy

I'm trying to schedule sports matches into timeslots and would like to not have empty timeslots during the day (so finish as early as possible). I think isEqual and isNotEqual should help, but stuck in the syntax of the Python version. I think I'm close (relevant code below)

in domain.py

```
@problem_fact
class Timeslot:
    def __init__(self, id, match_date, date_str, start_time, end_time):
        self.id = id
        self.match_date = match_date
        self.date_str = date_str # java does not have date or datetime equivalent so str also needed
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return (
                f"Timeslot("
                f"id={self.id}, "
                f"match_date={self.match_date}, "
                f"date_str={self.date_str}, "
                f"start_time={self.start_time}, "
                f"end_time={self.end_time})"
```

in constraints.py

```
def fill_pitches_from_start(constraint_factory):
    # A pitch should not be empty if possible
    return constraint_factory \
        .from_(TimeslotClass).ifNotExists(MatchClass, Joiners.equal(Timeslot.get_id(), Match.get_timeslot() ) )  \
        .join(TimeslotClass).ifExists(MatchClass, Joiners.equal(Timeslot.get_id(), Match.get_timeslot())) \
        .filter(lambda slot1, slot2: datetime.combine(slot1.date_str, slot1.timeslot.start_time) < datetime.combine(slot2.date_str, slot2.start_time) ) \
        .penalize("Pitch Empty with Later pitches populated", HardSoftScore.ofSoft(10))
```

This generates and expected error:
TypeError: get_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

But I can't work out the correct syntax - perhaps using lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close; this should work:

```
def fill_pitches_from_start(constraint_factory):
# A pitch should not be empty if possible
return constraint_factory \
    .forEach(TimeslotClass).ifNotExists(MatchClass, Joiners.equal(lambda timeslot: timeslot.get_id(), lambda match: match.get_timeslot() ) )  \
    .join(TimeslotClass).ifExists(MatchClass, Joiners.equal(lambda timeslot1, timeslot2: timeslot2.get_id(), lambda match: match.get_timeslot())) \
    .filter(lambda slot1, slot2: datetime.combine(slot1.date_str, slot1.timeslot.start_time) < datetime.combine(slot2.date_str, slot2.start_time) ) \
    .penalize("Pitch Empty with Later pitches populated", HardSoftScore.ofSoft(10))
```

It can probably be improved using `Joiners.lessThan`, but that would require an update to `optapy` first so Joiners can work with any Python type. (Will update this answer when `optapy` is updated to support said feature).

Comment: Many thanks - it runs and tells me True or False in a log. However, the results don't change. Is this linked to the planning_entity being the Match and the Timeslot being the problem_fact. How would the jointed TimeslotClass's MatchClass get penalised here instead of the initial TimeslotClass which has not got a MatchClass (yet)!?

Comment: I think I know the problem. There are multiple pitches to play a match on at the same time. So I need to know if there are any empty pitches all at the same time, so ifNotExists(MatchClass) will not really work as I need to know if the Timeslot has 8 MatchClasses if I have 8 pitches.

It gets more complicated a each pitch can have different timings, so I think I need to change the Timeslot class to include a pitch and generate Timeslots with pitches included (and drop the Pitch from the match and leave it only with the Timeslot).

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of how Constraint Streams work. Individual entities/problem facts are not penalized/rewarded. Instead, unique tuples are penalized (the tuples are created by the constraint factory). from_, groupBy and join modify the tuple. These tuples are then filtered by filters and joiners, and the ones that remain are penalized/rewarded. ifExists/ifNotExist do not modify the tuple and act as a filter. For this particular constraint, what being penalized is (timeslot1, timeslot2) where timeslot1 from from_ and timeslot2 from the join (provided it pass all the filters).

Comment: This particular constraint, as written above, reads "for each timeslot timeslot1 where there does not exist a match that has timeslot1 and there exists a timeslot timeslot2 where there exist a match that has timeslot2 and timeslot1 is before timeslot2, penalize the pair (timeslot1, timeslot2) by 10 soft."